# How to create link in <td> in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need like following

```
        <td>
        <a href="/Employee/Edit/1001320">Edit</a> |
       </td>
```

I wrote like following

```
var employeeaction = $('<td>').append('<a href="/Employee/Edit/'
        +element.id+'">Edit</a> |');
```

I parse table by the following code and took element.id

```
$('#EmployeeTable tr:not(:nth-child(1), :nth-child(2))').each(function () {
                // alert($(this).find('td').eq(0).text());
                var employee = {};
                employee.id = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
                employee.presenAddress = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
                employee.shortName = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
                employee.mobileNumber = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text();
                employee.department = $(this).find('td').eq(4).text();
                employee.designation = $(this).find('td').eq(5).text();
                employee.action = $(this).find('td').eq(6).text();
                employeeList.push(employee);
            });
```

when I click in it it gives me like

> localhost:10845/Employee/Edit/%201001097

I need

> localhost:10845/Employee/Edit/1001097

But it is not working. How can I do it?

Comment: What you have should work, but don't forget to append the td to a tr.

Comment: @RoyiNamir `$('<td>')` and `$('<td/>')` both function the same.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: Did you append the `td` to the DOM after creating it?

Comment: The `%20` is apparently because `element.id` begins with a space. Fix that and your problem should be solved.

Comment: %20 is the url encoding for a space. there's a space in the URL you're passing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do..

```
var $td = $('<td>').html('<a href="#">Foo</a>');
$('table tr:eq(0)').append($td);
```

Here's a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/etixof/1/edit

**Answer to your edit**

You just have a space before `element.id`. You should get it removed from there. If that's not an option you can do.

```
var $td = $('<td>').html('<a href="' + $.trim(element.id) + '">Foo</a>');
```

Comment: suppose total link is not hard coded. employee.id is a parameter. dynamically it changes.

Comment: thank a lot. its working now. I didn't give any space. I took it from dom. why space added to it?

Comment: check with alert(element.id);  sure its start with a space

Comment: I've never seen a space added randomly before an ID. Is your HTML goofy like `id=" 1001097"` or `id="\n1001097"`. PS: Your ids should **NOT** start with a number. Use a data attribute instead like `data-employee-id="1001097"`

Comment: see in my question. I didn't add space. I only parsed my table

Comment: If there's any space after `<td>` you'll also have space in `element.id`

Answer (score 3):

The `%20` in your URL is the escaped space character, meaning `element.id` is returning `_xxxxx` where the `_` is a space.

Fix your element ID's to remove the space, and it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are creating the link with a whitespace at the beginning.

You can solve it cleaning the value making use of [trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

```
var employeeaction = $('<td>').append('<a href="/Employee/Edit/'
        +$.trim(element.id)+'">Edit</a> |');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how u do it,

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").append("<a href='http://jsfiddle.net/7dYSG/'>Link to the solution on JS Fiddle</a>");
});
```

Comment: The link to JS Fiddle has a working example.

Comment: That'll append an anchor to every `td`, I don't *think* that's what's being asked

Comment: @billyonecan Yeah. But he just need to know how its done simply. Regardless of which td. This would only demonstrate the append.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xjgV7/)**

You must append your created `td` into the DOM. Consider the following markup:

```
<table>
    <tr id="row">
        <td>Hello World</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And in your jQuery code:

```
$('<td>')
    .append('<a href="/Employee/Edit/'+element.id+'">Edit</a>')

    // now insert it into the dom
    .appendTo('#row');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt` javascript function :

```
 $('<td>').append('<a href="/Employee/Edit/'
        +parseInt(element.id)+'">Edit</a> |');
```